# How are these two statements of the Gauss's Theorema Egregium equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry

In my notes the Gauss's Theorema Egregium is stated as follows
"The gaussian curvature of a $\mathbb R^3$ surface depends only on the metric and not on the Weingarten map(shape operator)"

But Wikipedia states it as: "The Gaussian curvature of a surface is invariant under local isometry"

How are these two statements equivalent?

Comment: Because the isometries preserve the distance, that's it, the intrinsic metric of the space where the manifold is

Comment: @Guillerminho77 But what do isometries have to do with the shape operator?

Comment: Because you can prove that the first fundamental form is preserved by isometries. Also the second fundamental form can be calculated trough the Christoffel's symbols, that also only depend on the first fundamental form. Thus the second fundamental form is also preserved by isometries. So also the shape operator. (I assume that shape operator is the Weingarten's matrix, im not native speaker)

Comment: No, isometric surfaces need not have the same second fundamental form. Not remotely. That’s the whole point. $K$ depends only on the metric, but the second fundamental form can vary quite a bit. @Guillerminho77’s comment is quite wrong. Try the simplest examples!